# When does Android media.image content provider gets updated

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

In my application I am using content provider media.image.external to get images uri and then write those uri to my Sqlite database.

But I want that my Sqlite database gets updated ( of any image add,delete,rename) in background as soon as the content provider media.image is updated.

Comment: Then you register a listener for the URI? Why are you querying a database, getting results, and then putting into your own SQLite database?

Comment: Purpose for putting it into own Sqlite is coz I want to have some more columns mapped to uri.

Comment: How do I register a listener for the uri

Comment: here you go: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/ basically when the underlying data changes a new cursor object is delivered. I'll assume you're not using a Cursor Loader (which automatically registers the URI for changes), as you are probably not using it directly coupled to a UI.

Comment: But I want that my database gets updated in background even if application is not launched.For this the Listener should run all tile  And if I use Listener ( content Observer or File Observer) then I have to unregister the listener  also.

Comment: You can have a Service implement the LoaderCallbacks and handle any data changes regardless of whether the app is open or closed, in fact I have this exact setup in a current project.  Whenever the data changes, do whatever you need to do with the new Cursor object then deliver a message/broadcast to your app from the service letting it know the data is stale and needs to use updated information. Only unregister the listener if the service is destroyed.

Comment: Sorry , but I am still not so convinced with your answer. Using LoaderCallback in Service class is fine but how do I get to know that the Content Provider database is updated.